# How to solve spring boot null probleme

Tags: spring-boot

**probleme** null dans spring boot run, i used a simple query function
@Query( "select p from Participant p  where p.user.id =:idA")
in the repository

[image]

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Could you please add your code, including your handler and where you return your ResponseEntity please?

Answer (score 0):

So there could be two problems here:

1. there is no data on your db so your DTO cannot access anything and returns null. To debug this just use `System.out.println` to print fields that should be filled. If fields you are expecting to be filled are not then you can check your repository, your dto and if you have data in your db.
2. there might be a problem with the JSON marshaller for the response. check this out on how to use `ResponseEntity` with springboot which handles that marshalling

Comment: There is data in db . Hiw yo check json problemz